# OpenMDAO SimpleGADriver penalty

Tags: genetic-algorithm, openmdao

In SimpleGADriver of OpenMDAO, is the penalty factor applied on the scaled constraint values or the original ones?

In my problem I have an objective and a few constraints each of different orders of magnitude, therefore I apply scaling factors when defining them, for instance: `model.add_objective('obj', ref=1e6)`. This way, at the driver level, I have all functions of the order of 1.

[image]

I set `penalty_exponent=2` and `penalty_parameter=20`, which are quite high, yet the driver seems to favour highly unfeasible points with low objective function value.

I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is applying the penalty to the scaled objectives and constraints. The relevant lines are [here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/genetic_algorithm_driver.py#L471-L515), and specifically lines

`obj_values = self.get_objective_values()`
and
`fun = obj + penalty * sum(np.power(constraint_violations, exponent))`

The `get_objective_values()` method by default returns thing in driver scaled values. The constraints work the same way.